# Python3 + matplotlib on Alpine error: ImportError: cannot import name 'get_backend'

Tags: python, docker, matplotlib, dockerfile

I have a micro service which build stopped working, probably because I have no explicit versions in my Dockerfile or requirements file. I do need help.

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache libpng freetype libstdc++ python3
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    gcc \
    build-base \
    python3-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    musl-dev \
    freetype-dev
RUN python -m ensurepip --default-pip
RUN ln -s /usr/include/locale.h /usr/include/xlocale.h \
    && pip install numpy \
    && pip install matplotlib \
    && apk del .build-deps
```

When I'm using matplotlib I get this error:

```
from matplotlib import (
E   ImportError: cannot import name 'get_backend'
```

I saw info about it, but couldn't resolve this issue. Can someone help?

Comment: can you post your code where you're using matplotlib and also the folder structure/your .py name?

Comment: You should be able to use python 3.6.6 or lower to get this working; or wait for matplotlib 3.0.1 to be released (which should happen in the next few days).